# How to stop window order changing on multiple monitor setup in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, display

I've been having a problem since upgrading to Mavericks. I have two monitors and I have Excel on Monitor 1 (M1) and Thunderbird on Monitor 2 (M2), if I open TextEdit and move it to M1, then CMD+Tab back to Thunderbird, Excel moves above TextEdit on M1 despite it not being the window that just took focus.

How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a check-box that will turn this on/off. System Preferences > Mission Control > Automatically rearrange Spaces based on recent use